# db2 alter auto increment query stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I try to alter the table using DB2 stored procedure. Below is my code. I found the issue in alter query. But that same query executed perfectly in DB2 command line editor. I want to run the same query using stored procedure. kindly help me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MODIFYAUTOINCRE()
    SPECIFIC TEST
    RESULT SETS 1
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    LANGUAGE SQL
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SQL Stored Procedure 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE v_max INTEGER DEFAULT 0;--
    DECLARE stmt1 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE stmt2 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE name1 VARCHAR(100);

    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR

        SELECT MAX(LABEL_ID) FROM ESTORE.APPLICATION_LABELS;


    -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;

        FETCH cursor1 INTO v_max;
    IF (v_max > 0 ) THEN

    SET v_max=v_max+1;

        SET stmt1= 'ALTER TABLE APTR.APPLICATION_LABELS ALTER COLUMN LABEL_ID SET GENERATED AS IDENTITY (START WITH '||v_max||' INCREMENT BY 1 NO CACHE);';

        PREPARE name1 FROM stmt1;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE name1;

        commit;
    END IF;


END P1
```

ERROR:
An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "NTITY (START WITH 69".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.58.81

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL statements must not include statement terminators. Remove the trailing semicolon from `stmt1`.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure itself is not a problem, all of the syntax is correct (if you're talking about a current version of DB2 on Linux, UNIX or Windows) and it will compile.

However there are a number of other potential errors:

1. You query the table `ESTORE.APPLICATION_LABELS`, but then you alter `APTR.APPLICATION_LABELS`.
2. When you alter the table you should just use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... RESTART WITH X` instead of trying to change the entire `GENERATED` clause.
3. Not sure why you're declaring `cursor1` with return when you're consuming the cursor within the stored procedure.  For that matter, not sure why you're even using a cursor in the first place, when you can just `SELECT max(label_id) INTO v_max FROM ...`
4. You don't need to `PREPARE` your statement if you're going to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  Just `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt1;`